# politely asked if we would like to upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, do-release-upgrade

RE Kubuntu:

We used to get notified that a new release was available, and were politely asked if we would like to upgrade. I haven't seen that in a long time--like years. Did someone decide to stop that? Are we now forced to manually start a release upgrade from the command line?
Is Discover supposed to handle that?
Still using Kubuntu 20.04, waiting to be offered an upgrade.

I know I can manually start an upgrade, **that's not what I'm asking**. And yes, I have preferred "Normal" releases, **not LTS**. I'm trying to learn if a KDE release upgrader has gone missing.

Thanks,
Lance

Comment: Do not know if KDE works the same, but Ubuntu still has it.  It is possible that the notification is turned off/set to not notify.  Would check in software and updates settings.  Should have it set to LTS only, all upgrades, or none.

Comment: I got this note on all my systems. They are Ubuntu and Lubuntu though. Whether you get this depends on your settings in "Software and Updates".